# Complex XML validation with custom error msgs

Tags: xml, xpath, schematron

I've been looking for a technology which would allow me:

1. to validate a **complex** (large structure, many optional sub/sequences of elements, fixed order, etc.) **XML**;
2. to define **custom error messages** for each check/block of checks/rule (XSD processor-like errors are no use for me);
3. to define the validation schema/rules effectively and in a **human readable** way if possible;

In other words, something like **Schematron** (allows custom error msgs, is readable, etc.] but still elegant for complex structural checks (XPath is kind of inefficient for things like order checking and such).

Is there some suitable technology which would fit the needs I described? I could live with Schematron and (outdated) tools like **XSD2SCH**, although result of using these tools seems to be really behemothic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try a mix of XSD and Schematron. Make use of the ordering, tag count, tage data type feature of XSD. Then for other complex validation you can make use of Schematron.

The error messages given by XSD are a bit difficult for humans but its quite powerful.

You can try to see if there are libraries that understand XSD 1.1 semantics. I didnt find the support when we had tried. So we resorted to combining XSD and Schematron